# C#. How to extract common logic in flexible way

Tags: c#, architecture, refactoring

I have two classes, A and B. They have a lot of common logic, but this logic is different in some places, for example:

```
CommonLogicClass {
    CommonMethod() {
        common1
        different1
        common2
        different2
    }
}
```

I don't believe the best method for this exists, but just want to know what methods are possible.

I found only two ways that are similar: pass parts that differ into the constructor of CommonLogicClass or make A and B implement interface and implement methods Different1() and Different2(), and after that use the interface instead parts that differ.

There are some problems with these methods. When I create 3-d class C with the same method I could need an additional part like in the example below:

```
CommonMethod() {
    common1
    different1
    common2
    different2
    additionalCodeOnlyForCClass
}
```

In this case, I will have to add empty actions or add a method to interface and implement it as an empty method in all classes except C.

Or I could have a worse case when common2 is only common for A and B but not for C:

```
CommonMethod() {
    common1
    different1 \
    different2 - (or just different1)
    different3 /
}
```

I will need to exclude common2 from common, make it different and add the same code for all classes except C.

So always there are a lot of changes when a minimum of logic changed or added. What are other more flexible ways to extract common logic? Maybe there are some patterns that I should learn or some books I should read to answer questions about architecture like this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for the template method pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Make an abstract base class that implements the functionality that is common. Implement differences in the sub-classes.

```
void Main()
{
    LogicBase a = new ClassA();
    a.CommonMethod();

    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");

    LogicBase b = new ClassB();
    b.CommonMethod();
}

public class LogicBase
{
    public void CommonMethod()
    {
        DoSomething_1();
        DoSomething_2();
        DoSomething_3();
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething_1()
    {
        // Default behaviour 1
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething_1 - Hello from LogicBase");
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething_2()
    {
        // Default behaviour 2
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething_2 - Hello from LogicBase");

    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething_3()
    {
        // Default behaviour 3
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething_3 - Hello from LogicBase");
    }
}

public class ClassA : LogicBase
{
    protected override void DoSomething_2()
    {
        // Behaviour specific to ClassA
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething_2 - Hello from ClassA");
    }
}

public class ClassB : LogicBase
{
    protected override void DoSomething_3()
    {
        // Behaviour specific to ClassB
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething_3 - Hello from ClassB");
    }
}
```

Running the code gives the following output:

```
DoSomething_1 - Hello from LogicBase
DoSomething_2 - Hello from ClassA
DoSomething_3 - Hello from LogicBase
----------------------------
DoSomething_1 - Hello from LogicBase
DoSomething_2 - Hello from LogicBase
DoSomething_3 - Hello from ClassB
```

Comment: It could be a solution too, but I think this one as flexible as mine. Maybe what I'm looking for is not impossible... But thank you for the answer.